# ¿Hay partes o momentos donde el español empiece a perder sentido?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, sintaxis

A lo que me refiero es que una frase sea correcta (gramatical y semánticamente), pero aún así es complicada de entender o de traducir a otros idiomas.

Un ejemplo en inglés sería :

> Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo

(enlace a la explicación en [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo))

Comment: @walen la palabra "bajo" da mucho juego: _Me bajo los bajos y abajo bajo, bajo el bajo en los bajos los bajos bajos cantaré._

Comment: _La banda lava lavanda para la banda la banda a la banda la banda._ (La pandilla lava lavanda para la faja del conjunto de música al costado del grupo armado.) Omito algunas preposiciones como en "un bocata mortadela".